# Measuring big stuff

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, measure-theory, large-cardinals

Often during informal discussion with colleagues, the following pattern emerges when we are stuck trying to prove a theorem about $x \in X$.

**A**: "*let's assume this hypothesis $H$ on $x$*"
**B**: "*most elements of $X$ do not satisfy $H$*".
**A**: (censored to protect the innocent).

Of course this makes sense when one restricts to a set $X$ equipped with a sigma algebra and measure, but what happens when you want to measure much larger things? Here are some example off-hand statements that sound reasonable:

1. Most topological spaces are not Hausdorff.
2. Most categories contain a non-identity morphism.

> Is there any logical framework that makes this sort of informal statement precise?

I suppose that one of the most basic statements of this type would be "Most sets are infinite", so one sane approach would involve some correspondence of the form

$$\Omega: \text{[Classes or Large Categories]} \to \text{[Cardinals or Ordinals]}$$

that copies the basic properties of a measure on $\mathbb{R}$. There has been some prior discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17473/measure-theory-for-regular-cardinals) on extending the range of $\Omega$, but (as you can see from the informal statements above) my primary interest is in extending the domain beyond Sets. Sorry about the fuzzy question, but hopefully there are others who share my experience and want to know.

Comment: I think that saying that most sets are infinite is much like saying that most rational numbers are proper fractions. It's true in some sense, but very false in another. And the question is whether one seeks a measure of cardinality (even for classes), in which there are as many singletons as there are sets; or does one seek a measure theoretic-like tool or a topological density-equivalent, in which it would make sense to say "there are more of this proper class than this proper class, despite the existence of a bijection between them". 

Comment: (in addition to my previous comment, note that measure theoretically there are as many integers as there are points in the Cantor set; and topologically speaking there are more rational numbers than there are points in the Cantor set... so all these notions are very very different from one another as measurements of size)

Comment: Asaf, either you don't get my question or I don't get your comments. Saying that measure theoretically there are as many integers as Cantor points assumes the existence of a common measure space (maybe Reals with Lebesgue measure?) into which both parties can inject, and then you use that implicitly assumed measure to compare. The fact that another measure (or another common space) might yield a different answer hardly undermines the usefulness of measure theory itself.

Comment: Well, of course that I meant the Lebesgue measure (and the standard topology for the other one). I was remarking that to say that "most sets are infinite" is an extremely ambiguous thing to say, and it makes it slightly difficult to guess what you are aiming for (at least for me). You wrote that the question is fuzzy, and I pointed out something which for me makes it harder to focus on your intention, that is all.

Comment: Asaf, "most sets are infinite" is ambiguous precisely because we do not yet agree on a way to measure sub-classes of the class of all sets (independently of whether or not we agree to treat two sets as equal in this class if there exists a set-bijection between them). The question asks whether there is a measure theory on classes which provides some framework for making such statements non-ambiguous. 

Comment: If I interpret correctly the question, there's a difference between "most rationals are proper fractions" and "most sets are infinite", in that in the former case we've got a crystal clear framework (in fact, more than one: at least measure theory and topology) to compare the part and the whole, whereas in the latter case we lack a sensible and useful framework. (...)

Comment: (...) Of course there are as many Abelian groups as there are groups (a proper class thereof, or a well determined cardinal if you only count groups below a certain fixed cardinality of elements), but we would nevertheless like to be able to say rigorously that "most groups are not Abelian".

Comment: Motivated by a rereading of Qwfwq's comment above, here is a suggestion: consider instead the lattice of subvarieties of groups, which is dual to the lattice of (some modifier which eludes me, perhaps invariant?) congruences on a free countably generated group. One can try a measure on either lattice to make sense of the statement "most groups are Abelian", since many classes of groups of interest are equational classes or closely related (e.g. quasivarieties).  Gerhard "Seeking Measures Which Measure Up" Paseman, 2012.11.23

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since any measure on a set can be transferred isomorphically to a
measure on any set of the same cardinality, and furthermore every
nonempty set has full measure with respect to *some* measure, your
initial remarks have a greater force only in a context where we
have an agreed-upon or natural measure.

From this perspective, I take the question to be: what kind of
natural measures do we have for measuring extremely large sets or
even proper classes?

For this, set theory has a lot to say. First of all, for any
cardinal $\kappa$ with uncountable cofinality, we have the measure
arising from the club filter, which gives measure one to any set
containing a closed unbounded subset of $\kappa$ and measure zero
to those omitting a club. This is a $\sigma$-additive (and indeed
$\kappa$-additive for regular $\kappa$ or more generally
$\text{cof}(\kappa)$-additive) two-valued measure. The [stationary
sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37502/what-is-the-idea-behind-stationary-sets/37504#37504) are precisely the sets that are positive with respect to
this measure, and it is interesting to note that these are also precisely the sets that
could become measure one with respect to the club filter measure
in a forcing extension of the universe. The club and stationary
concepts are extremely robust concepts of largeness that are used
throughout set theory.

Meanwhile, second, much of large cardinal set theory is about the
possibility of various kinds of measures on extremely large sets.
For example, every measurable cardinal has what is called a
*normal* measure, a $\kappa$-additive two-valued measure on
$\kappa$ measuring every subset of $\kappa$, with the additional
property that every regressive function is constant on a measure
one set. Similar notions of normality and fineness of measures
arise with other large cardinals, such as for strongly compact
cardinals and supercompact cardinals. For example, $\kappa$ is
strongly compact if and only if every $\kappa$-additive two-valued
measure on a set can be extended to a $\kappa$-additive two-valued
measure measuring every subset of the set. We have hierarchies of
measures in the Mitchell order and the Rudin-Keisler orders.

As for proper classes, many of these same ideas still apply. For
example, the club filter measure concept still makes sense for
proper classes (although this becomes a second-order or
scheme-expressable notion), since we can say in first order that a
given proper class $C\subset\text{Ord}$ is closed and unbounded.
The hypothesis [Ord is Mahlo](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37502/what-is-the-idea-behind-stationary-sets/37504#37504) is the hypothesis that the class of regular cardinals have outer measure
one with respect to that natural measure. One can similarly extend
the notion to concepts of ``Ord is hypermahlo'' and so on. All
these notions provide natural concepts of largeness for proper
classes.

Comment: "Ord is Mahlo" should say that the class of regular cardinals has *outer* measure 1, i.e., it's stationary, not that it has measure 1 which would mean that it includes a club.

Answer (score 1):

One can construct a framework to analyze these questions, but not without giving up
something.

Almost all finite algebras (of finite similarity type, on a labeled set, and other
technicalities which apply) generate finitely based varieties in universal algebra.
This is justified by looking at multiplication tables on an underlying set of n elements,
choosing a subset of them that satisfy a certain property, computing a ratio R(n),
and then showing that this ratio goes to 1 as n grows.  Note that it is no longer 
looking at "all" finite algebras, but at representatives of such, and the ratio R(n)
may have a limit which may bear no relation to an analogous quantity defined
for countably infinite algebras: R() might not be continuously extended to all
cardinals or even enough ordinals.

One can try a similar framework for arbitrary cardinalities, using the appropriate
notions of measure as suggested in Joel Hamkins's post.  Let me suggest an
alternative idea which may make sense.  Consider a set sized collection of structures,
as well as the associated theory describing a class containing that set.  Ideally the
collection can be embedded in a large model of the same theory, and one can now
ask if there are models that exist in which the set is embedded and the ratio R
of some subset is as large or as small as possible, relative to a measure on the
large model and using certain minimality considerations to avoid trivial and
uninteresting consequences.

If you are still interested in looking at "all" structures, you will still need a container
to hold them.  I do not know about functors from the "power category" of a category
to the reals, but if I were to attempt measuring inside a category, that is where I would
start.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.11.22

Comment: For groups there is the similar concept of a random group (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_group):