# Does pointwise convergence imply uniform convergence on a large subset?

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis

Suppose $f_n$ is a sequence of real valued functions on $[0,1]$ which converges pointwise to zero.

1. Is there an uncountable subset $A$ of $[0,1]$ so that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $A$?
2. Is there a subset $A$ of $[0,1]$ of cardinality the continuum so that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $A$?

Background: Egoroff's theorem implies that the answer to (2) is yes if all $f_n$ are Lebesgue measurable. It is not hard to show that the answer to (1) is yes if you change "uncountable" to "infinite".

Motivation: I thought about this question while teaching real analysis this term but could not solve it even after looking at some books, googling, and asking some colleagues who are much smarter than I, so I assigned it as a problem (well, an extra credit problem) to my class. Unfortunately, no one gave me a solution.

ADDED 11-12-10: Thanks for all the great answers.  I accepted Jonas' answer since it was the first one.

Comment: This is the best question I have ever seen.

Comment: Of course, for your questions it is only the cardinality of [0,1] that is important, not any topological or measure-space structure we might usually put on it. I assume you phrased it this way to highlight the contrast with Egoroff's theorem?

Comment: convergeness ??

Comment: My one remaining desire, an answer from Jonas Meyer, has been fulfilled. Now I rest.

Comment: The paper "Small Combinatorial Cardinal Characteristics and Theorems of Ergorov and Blumberg" by Krzysztof Ciesielski and Janusz Pawlikowski, Real Analysis Exchange, p905-912, might be useful here.  It seems to imply that the answer to your question is "yes" for some SUBSEQUENCE of the $f_n$, subject to the consistency with ZFC of certain hypotheses about Ramsey ultrafilters and dominating numbers. The paper is on Project Euclid. Here's a link: http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.rae/1214571379

Comment: @ SJR: By replacing $f_n$ with $g_n := \sup_{k \ge n} f_k$, the questions reduce to the case where the sequence is pointwise decreasing to zero, so a result for a subsequence gives the same result for the sequence. 

Thanks for the reference.

Comment: The following generalization also sounds interesting. If $f_n$ is a sequence of real valued functions on a set A converging pointwise to zero, for what cardinalities $\kappa$ can we guarantee the existence of a subset $B\subseteq A$ with $\vert B\vert=\kappa$ on which it converges uniformly? And for what $\kappa$ can we guarantee the existence of such a subset with $\vert A\setminus B\vert=\kappa$?

Comment: @BillJohnson This is very late considering the time since you asked this question. I have nothing to add to the answers or the question. But it'll be of great knowledge to me if you could elaborate on a comment that you made in your "background".  You stated that in part (1) if we simply have the condition of $A$ being infinite, then (1) can be "easily" proved. I am embarassed to state that i couldnt do that. It would mean a lot if you shed some light on the stated comment. Does it hold for any sequence of pointwise convergent functions ? No need for complete proof, just some direction suffice

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I did some Googling and came up with something that looks relevant, [Theorem 10](https://books.google.com/books?id=WwmvxtDlz9UC&lpg=PA124&ots=lcdSy9gacd&dq=point%2520set%2520theorem%2520morgan&pg=PA88#v=onepage&q&f=false) quoted below from Morgan's *Point set theory*. It cites works of Sierpiński from the late 1930s, but I can't tell what works are cited because the preview won't let me see that page in the references.

> The existence of a linear set having the power of the continuum that is concentrated on a denumerable set is equivalent to the existence of a pointwise convergent sequence of functions of a real variable that does not converge uniformly on any uncountable set.

Comment: The existence of a set of reals of the cardinality of continuum which is concentrated on a countable set is a known consequence of the continuum hypothesis. 

Comment: Thanks, Jonas, and everyone else for the information.  If any of you offers a class in Googling for Math I will enroll.

Answer (score 27):

A simple diagonalization argument gives a counterexample if you assume the continuum hypothesis.  Let a modulus of convergence be a sequence $\delta:{\mathbb N}\to(0,\infty)$ which converges to 0, and say that $\delta>\delta'$ if $\delta(n)>\delta'(n)$ for sufficiently large $n$.  By diagonalizing, for any countable set $\{\delta_n\}$ of sequences there is some $\Delta$ (which still converges to 0) such that $\Delta>\delta_n$ for all $n$.

We say that a sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$ with modulus $\delta$ if $|x_n-x|<\delta(n)$ for all $n$.  We then have that $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly iff there is a single $\delta$ such that $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ with modulus $\delta$ for all $x$.

Now assuming the continuum hypothesis, the set of all moduli and the set of all points in $[0,1]$ are both in bijection with $\omega_1$; let $(\delta_\alpha)_{\alpha<\omega_1}$ and $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\omega_1}$, respectively, be enumerations.  For each $\alpha$, let $\Delta_\alpha$ be a modulus such that $\Delta_\alpha>\delta_\beta$ for all $\beta<\alpha$ (since there are only countably many such $\beta$).  Now let $f=0$ and define $f_n(x_\alpha)=\Delta_\alpha(n)$.  Then $f_n(x_\alpha)$ converges to $f(x_\alpha)=0$ for all $x_\alpha$.  However, for any fixed modulus $\delta=\delta_\beta$, $f_n(x_\alpha)$ cannot converge with modulus $\delta$ for $\alpha>\beta$ by construction, so there are only countably many points on which $f_n$ converges uniformly with modulus $\delta$.

Comment: Nice, simple argument, Eric. 

Answer (score 16):

To add a bit to Jonas Meyer's answer.

Sierpiński's result was first published in *C.R. Soc. Sc. Varsovie* 1928, p. 84-87. It was reproduced in his monograph [*"Hypothèse du continu"*](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/mon/mon04/mon0403.pdf) (Lwów, 1934, p. 52):

> **Proposition $C_9$.** Il existe une suite infinie convergente de fonctions d'une variable   réelle
>   $f_1(x)$, $f_2(x)$, $f_3(x),...$ qui convergent non uniformément  sur tout ensemble indénombrable.

Sierpiński effectively derived it from the statement which is implied by the continuum hypothesis (Ibid. p. 36):

> **Proposition $C_1$.**  Il existe un ensemble linéaire $N$ de puissance du continu qui admet un ensemble au plus dénombrable de points communs avec tout ensemble (linéaire) parfait non-dense.

Comment: **Proposition $C_9$.** There exists a converging infinite sequence of functions of a real variable  $f_1(x)$, $f_2(x)$, $f_3(x),...$ which converges non-uniformly on every uncountable set.

Comment: **Proposition $C_1$.**  There exists a set of reals $N$ of the cardinality of continuum such that its intersection  with every perfect nowhere dense set of reals is at most countable.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I didn't know Sierpiński's monograph was available online.

Answer (score 12):

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512546) by R. Pinciroli claims that the stronger statement:

> $f_n$ converges uniformly on sets of outer measure arbitrarily close to 1

is undecidable in ZFC.

Comment: So the answer is both yes and no to question 1.  Is it provable in ZFC that sets of positive outer measure have cardinality the continuum?

Comment: Bill, it is independent of ZFC.  See this answer of Joel David Hamkins: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8972/do-sets-with-positive-lebesgue-measure-have-same-cardinality-as-r/9027#9027 or this expository note by Briggs and Schaffter: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2320153.

Answer (score 5):

Also, [Shinoda (1973)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.nmj/1118798877) proved that if Martin's Axiom and $\neg CH$ hold, then the answer to 1) si affirmative.