# Pointwise convergence imples uniform convergence in an infinite subset

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, limits-and-convergence

I came upon this statement in a stack answer.

Statement :
If $f_n$ is a sequence of real valued functions (not necessarily continuous or measurable) on $[0,1]$ such that $f_n$ converges point-wise to $0$, then there exists an infinite subset of $[0,1]$ where the convergence is uniform.

I couldn't prove it. I believe the claim is true because $[0,1]$ is uncountable but the set of sequences is countable only.

Any help would be appreciated in assistance to how to prove it.

Comment: If $\mathfrak{c}$ is a real-valued measurable cardinal then this follows from Egorov's theorem...

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45784/does-pointwise-convergence-imply-uniform-convergence-on-a-large-subset?rq=1 says this is "not hard" but doesn't give a proof.  (It mainly discusses whether "infinite" can be strengthened to "uncountable".)

Comment: Crossposted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4196015/pointwise-implies-uniform-convergence-on-infinite-subset: when you do this, please make sure each question contains a link to the other.

Comment: @NateEldredge apologies. I'll remember that in the future.

Comment: @NateEldredge I saw that answer. I have commented on the question seeking an explanation, but the question is 10yrs old, so don't know how helpful that would be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For every sequence $(F_n)_{n \in \omega}$ with $F_n:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ converging pointwise to $0$, we can associate to every $x \in [0,1]$ an $f_x \in \mathbb{\omega}^\omega$ in the following way: Set $f_x(m):= \min\{n \in \mathbb{\omega}\,\, \colon \,\, \forall n' \geq n \,\,\,\,  \vert F_{n'}(x) \vert < \frac{1}{m}\}$.

Now the proof works in two steps.

In the **first step** we show that there exists $f^* \in \omega^\omega$ such that for every $k \in \omega$ the set $\{x \in [0,1] \,\, \colon \,\, f_x \restriction k \leq f^* \restriction k\}$ is uncountable.

We will construct such an $f^* \in \omega^\omega$ by induction on $k \in \omega$: Assume that $f^* \restriction k$ has already been constructed, and we have that the set $\{x \in [0,1] \,\, \colon \,\, f_x \restriction k \leq f^* \restriction k\}$ is uncountable. Since $$\{x \in [0,1] \,\, \colon \,\, f_x \restriction k \leq f^* \restriction k\}= \bigcup_{l \in \omega}\,\, \{x \in [0,1] \,\, \colon \,\, f_x \restriction (k+1) \leq (f^* \restriction k)^\frown l\}$$ we find $l \in \omega$ such that $\{x \in [0,1] \,\, \colon \,\, f_x \restriction (k+1) \leq (f^* \restriction k)^\frown l\}$ is uncountable. Now set $f^*(k)=l$ and we see that $f^*\restriction (k+1)$ has the required properties.

In the **second step** we inductively construct $(x_k)_{k \in \omega} \subseteq [0,1]$ injective and $(f_k)_{k \in \omega} \subseteq \omega^\omega$ increasing such that for every $k \in \omega$ we have $f^* \leq f_k$ ,  $f_{x_k} \leq f_k$ and $f_k \restriction (k+1) = f_{k+1} \restriction (k+1)$. Once we have shown this, we can define $g \in \omega^\omega$ such that $g(k):=f_k(k)$ and see that $f_{x_k} \leq g$ for every $k \in \omega$. But this proves that $(F_n)_{n \in \omega}$ converges uniformly on $(x_k)_{k \in \omega}$.

To this end assume that $x_0,...,x_{k-1}$ and $f_0,...f_{k-1}$ with the required properties have already been constructed. Since $\{x \in [0,1] \,\, \colon \,\, f_x \restriction k \leq f^* \restriction k\}$ is uncountable, we can find $x_k \in \{x \in [0,1] \,\, \colon \,\, f_x \restriction k \leq f^* \restriction k\}$ different from $x_0,...,x_{k-1}$. Set $f_k(m):=\max\{f_{k-1}(m), f_{x_k}(m)\}$, and note that since $f_{x_k} \restriction k \leq f^* \restriction k \leq f_{k-1} \restriction k$, we have $f_{k-1}\restriction k =f_k \restriction k$. This finishes the proof.

Comment: Here $\omega$ denotes the set of natural numbers, and for every $k \in \omega$ we have $k=\{0,...,k-1\}$.

Also note that the proof cannot be much simpler, since your statement holds iff for every $(f_x)_{x \in [0,1]} \subseteq \omega^\omega$ there exists $X \subseteq [0,1]$ infinite and $g \in \omega^\omega$ such that $f_x \leq g$ for every $x \in X$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.