# A set of positive measure with cardinality less than that of the continuum?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Is it consistent with ZFC that there is a subset of $[0,1]$ whose cardinality is less than that of the continuum but which has positive Lebesgue measure?

Obviously not given CH.  And, given ZFC, there is such a subset iff there is a subset of full measure that has cardinality less than that of the continuum.  Moreover, I think it follows from the consistency of ZFC with the non-existence of Sierpinski subsets of $[0,1]^2$ that it is consistent with ZFC that there is a subset of $[0,1]$ whose cardinality is less than that of the continuum and which has positive *outer* Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Inner regularity of Lebesgue measure implies that every set with positive measure has a Cantor subset of positive measure.  This is contained in undergraduate courses in real analysis, so I vote to close. 

Comment: @Bill, in fairness, not in everyone's course on measure theory (although perhaps I just didn't do that particular homework exercise that week)

Comment: I wonder now: Is it consistent with ZFC that there is a translation-invariant extension of Lebesgue measure that assigns non-zero measure to some set of cardinality less than the continuum?  Maybe I should make that a separate question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. It is a famous exercise that if $X\subset\mathbf{R}$ has positive measure then $X-X$ contains an interval. It follows that $X$ has cardinality continuum.

Comment: Thanks!  I was about to delete my question in light of <a href="http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8972/do-sets-with-positive-lebesgue-measure-have-same-cardinality-as-r">this</a> (which has good information on related stuff) and then I saw your very quick answer.

Comment: Link was bad: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8972/do-sets-with-positive-lebesgue-measure-have-same-cardinality-as-r

Comment: Alternatively, if $X\subset[0,1]$ has positive measure, find $x\in[0,1]$ such that $[0,x]\cap X$ and $[x,1]\cap X$ both have positive measure. Then find $x_0$ and $x_1$ such that $0<x_0<x<x_1<1$ and $X$ has positive measure in each of the intervals $[0,x_0]$, $[x_0,x]$, $[x,x_1]$, $[x_1,1]$. Continue subdividing, and find continuum-many points in $X$.

Comment: Aha, yes, that question includes information about the non-measurable case, which I ignored.

Comment: @Sean: Concerning your comment about repeated subdivision, did you intend the "continuum-many points" in the last sentence to be the limits of the subdivision points?  If so, how do you know they're in $X$.  If not, which continuum-many points did you mean?

Comment: @AndreasBlass I should've added that by inner regularity you can find a closed subset also of positive measure. Now apply that argument.

Comment: Another proof is here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/125563/is-it-consistent-with-zfc-that-there-is-a-translation-invariant-extension-of-lebe