# Smallest size of a non-measurable set of reals

Tags: set-theory, independence-results, cardinal-characteristics

The question is pretty much the title. I'm wondering if anything is known about the smallest size $\kappa$ of a non-measurable subset of the real numbers (regarding the Lebesgue measure). Since we have $\kappa\geq\aleph_0$ and $\kappa\leq\mathfrak{c}$ with $\kappa=\mathfrak{c}$ at least being consistent (under CH or MA), it might be an interesting cardinal invariant to look at.

Comment: If I look at the Wikipedia articles [Cardinal characteristic of the continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum&oldid=931455642)) and 
[Cichon's diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicho%C5%84%27s_diagram) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cicho%C5%84%27s_diagram&oldid=934668057)), it seems that this is the cardinal denoted $\operatorname{non}(\mathcal N)$ and $\operatorname{non}(\mathcal L)$.

Comment: Knowing this notation might help when searching for results about this cardinal. (And perhaps also some of the references given in those Wikipedia articles might contains some pointers.)

Comment: I wasnt aware of the connection to $\text{non}(\mathcal{N})$. So does this just follow, because we can carry out the Vitali construction on any set of positive and finite measure and therefore obtain, for every non-nullset $M$, a non-measurable set $N\subseteq M$?

Comment: Well, a measurable set of positive measure necessarily has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.  So if it has cardinality less than $\mathfrak{c}$ and isn't null, it must already be non-measurable.

Comment: Two precise questions (to start with): (a) is it consistent under ZFC that every subset of reals of cardinal $\aleph_1$ is measurable (hence null)? (b) Is it consistent under ZFC that CH fails and there exists a non-measurable subset of cardinal $\aleph_1$?

Comment: @YCor Yes to both.

Comment: Here is a link to a post about "set of positive measure has cardinality $\mathfrak c$": [Cardinality of a set of positive Lebesgue measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1054348).

Comment: This post seems also related to the above comments: [Do sets with positive Lebesgue measure have same cardinality as R?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/8972)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just going to compile the comments into an answer so i can close this question.

Claim: The smallest size of a non-measurable set is $\text{non}(\mathcal{L})$:

$\geq$: If $A$ is non-measurable, then $A$ is not null.

$\leq$: If $A$ is not null and not of size continuum, then $A$ has to be non-measurable, because the difference set of any set of positive measure has to contain an interval around $0$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus_theorem) and therefore be of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$. Because furthermore, the cardinality of the difference set is less than or equal to the cardinality of $A\times A$ which is equinumerous with $A$, $A$ is of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.

Therefore either $\text{non}(\mathcal{L})=\mathfrak{c}$ and $\leq$ is trivial or there is a non-null set of cardinality $<\mathfrak{c}$ which, by the argument above, also is a non-measurable set.